# PHP - PDO - Form Validation - Insert statement gets executed even when errors exist

Tags: php, mysql, validation, error-handling, pdo

I didn't notice it until I finished the validation but I realized that even when my errors appear on top of my form box I then go to phpmyadmin and I look at the data, and even if I purposely added errors the form will be submitted.

Then my second problem including the one stated above, no matter what I do the student Id or "anum" is not posting. it continues to give me a "0" value in the students table in my database.

This is the entire code:

```
<?php
//Starting session
session_start();

// Validation starts here
if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $errors   = array();
    $anum     = $_POST['anum'];
    $first    = $_POST['first'];
    $last     = $_POST['last'];
    $why      = $_POST['why'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    if (empty($anum) === true || empty($first) === true || empty($last) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Form is incomplete please revise it!';
    } else {

        if (ctype_alnum($anum) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'A number can only consist of alphanumeric characters!';
        }
        if ((strlen($anum) < 9) && (strlen($anum)) > 9) {
            $errors[] = 'A number is incorrect!';
        }
        if (ctype_alpha($first) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'First mame must only contain alphabetical characters!';
        }
        if (ctype_alpha($last) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Last name must only contain alphabetical characters!';
        }
        if (empty($why))
            $errors[] = 'Please make sure to select the proper reasoning for your vistit today!';

        elseif ($why === 'Other') {

            if (empty($comments))
                $errors[] = 'Please explain the nature of your visit in the comments box!';

            else {

                if (strlen($comments) < 15)
                    $errors[] = 'Your explaination is short, please revise!';

                if (strlen($comments) > 45)
                    $errors[] = 'Your explaintion is to long, please revise!';

            }

        }

        if (empty($errors) === false) {
            header('location: signedin.php');
            exit();
        }

        // Validations ends here

        $host     = "localhost"; // Host name
        $username = "root"; // Mysql username
        $password = "testdbpass"; // Mysql password
        $db_name  = "test"; // Database name

        // Connect to server via PHP Data Object
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        try {
            $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `students` (anum, FIRST, LAST, why, comments)
                                   VALUES (:anum, :FIRST, :LAST, :why, :comments)");

            $query->execute(

                array(
                    'anum'     => $_POST['anum'],
                    'first'    => $_POST['first'],
                    'last'     => $_POST['last'],
                    'why'      => $_POST['why'],
                    'comments' => $_POST['comments']
                ));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        $dbh = null;

    }

}
?>

<html>
<body>
<title>Student Signin Form</title>
<table width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
    <tr>
        <?php
        if (empty($errors) === false) {
            echo '<h3>';
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                echo '<center><li>', $error, '</li></center>';
            }

            echo '<h3>';
        }
        ?>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <tr>

                <tr colspan="3">
                    <center></center>
                    <strong>Student Signin Form</strong></tr>
                <p>Student ID Number: <input type="text" name="anum" <?php if (isset($_POST['anum']) === true) {
                        echo 'value="', $_POST['anum'], '"';
                    } ?> />

                <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first" <?php if (isset($_POST['first']) === true) {
                        echo 'value="', $_POST['first'], '"';
                    } ?> />

                <p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" <?php if (isset($_POST['last']) === true) {
                        echo 'value="', $_POST['last'], '"';
                    } ?> />

                <p>How may we help you? <select name="why"/>
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="Appeal">Appeal</option>
                    <option value="Other">Other: Please specify the nature of your visit bellow</option>
                    </select>
                    </tr>


                    <br>

                <P>If other please describe the issue you are having.</P>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name="comments" <?php if (isset($_POST['comments']) === true) {
                    echo 'value="', $_POST['comments'], '"';
                } ?>></textarea>


                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"/>

    </form>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: don't understand your question

Comment: My problem that I am having is that when I test out my errors validation (to see if a student "anum" is typed) for some reason the error comes out AND the form is submitted. So the problem is that the form has errors and is still being submitted. That is a problem as it will bloat the table that the code is writing to.

Comment: It's all a matter of variable initialisation: why don't you simply use `$errors= array();` and do a `if (count($errors) > 0) ` instead of using unreliable code with guesses if a variable has been created and contains some type of value?

Comment: You are validating data at server side so you have to submit form

Comment: Your coding style is very confusing. `blah === false` should be `!blah`, and `blah === true` should just be `blah`.

Comment: @Barmar: In PHP that is not the same. So please do not just suggest that.

Comment: @hakre It's true for functions like `empty()` that only return booleans, which is all his cases.

Comment: Yes but the argumentation in your comment is misleading and potentially wrong and dangerous. And don't talk about coding style when writing *blah* please. It needs some care to take, so take it. I can see you want to, just do it *better*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging up and more understanding of what I was actually doing (the wrong way) I came up with my solution. Pretty much I had to make it so that the Mysql insert statements were a part of the error validation not stand-a-lone. If you look at my prior code the PDO statements had no real place in the code, it was just there. The cause of this was

```
if (empty($errors) === false) {
        header('location: signedin.php');
        exit();
    }
```

What this was doing was even if there were errors I had to still redirect to the "signedin.php" that is not the desired affect. What had to be done was first change it from false to true.

```
if (empty($errors) === true) {
        header('location: signedin.php');
        exit();
    }
```

Then after doing so you must then input your PDO statements in between the {}.

So then what this means is that if the script has picked up errors it will NOT run the PDO insert.

However if it is TRUE that there are no errors it will run the insert script with a error check for that script, then if it inserts correctly it will then redirect the user to the next page.

Example :

```
if (empty($errors) === true) 
{
            $host="localhost"; // Host name
            $username="root"; // Mysql username
            $password="testdbpass"; // Mysql password
            $db_name="test"; // Database name


            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;", $username, $password);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

                    try 
        {
                            $query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `students` (anum, first, last, why, comments) 
                                   VALUES (:anum, :first, :last, :why, :comments)");

                            $query->execute(
                                                array(
                                                        'anum'      => $_POST['anum'],
                                                        'first'     => $_POST['first'],
                                                        'last'      => $_POST['last'],
                                                        'why'       => $_POST['why'],
                                                        'comments'  => $_POST['comments']
                                                        )); 
        }
                catch (PDOException $e) 
        {
                error_log($e->getMessage());
                die($e->getMessage());
        }
   $dbh = null;    

        header('location: signedin.php');
        exit(); 
}
```

Hopefully some one will find this of any use.

Comment: Resources : http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10373021-RESOLVED-Form-validation-then-insert-into-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you are writing some code without actually testing it if it works or not. Take a look for example at these lines (around ca. line 50):

```
        if (empty($errors) === false) {
            header('location: signedin.php');
            exit();
        }
```

You are filling the `$errors` array with error messages. Then you're doing the redirect if there were errors. Doesn't make sense because this does also remove the error messages.

Comment: Well isn't that code you added supposed to stop if there are errors? if errors are empty = false = there are errors.

Comment: As written, if there are errors, you are doing the redirect. This will effectively delete all error messages and will tell the user to request `signedin.php` next. All error information is discarded at the point of `exit();`. I can not imagine that this is intended.

Comment: yes you are right. I'm still stuck on the logic as you stated earlier. I'm just re-looking over everything. Pretty much the way I have it set up validation -> errors -> checks for errors -> errors present -> then the code above that you copy and pasted (i turned the false to true) and the problem still occurs. so I'm still at step one. I purposely cause an error and the form still gets inputted. So you recommend working out the logic?

Comment: I can just do the SQL stuff after if(empty($errors) === true) { PDO SQL stuff here } header (....)... I'm going to try that out and see if it gives me the desired affect